# Upload image to a google drive using google drive api programatically in android

Tags: android, file-upload, image-uploading, google-drive-android-api

I am able to uploading a text file to folder in google drive using google drive android api .[Sample code](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileActivity.java)

But i would like to uplaod a image to google drive .Is it possible?

code for create text file:

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }
        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                try {
                    writer.write("Hello World!");
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("New file")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true).build();

                // create a file on root folder
                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                        .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
    }
};
```

Now i need MimeType("image/jpeg") and i have to change OutputStreamWriter?

Any help appreciated..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING : The Drive Android API is deprecated as of December 6, 2018 and will be turned down on December 6, 2019. Hence you shouldn't upload images to Google Drive for storage purpose, you should use Firebase / other solutions**

Your code is for uploading Text File. To upload a Image file, use below code:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;


private void saveFileToDrive() {

    final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {

            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.i("ERROR", "Failed to create new contents.");
                return;
            }


            OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
            // Write the bitmap data from it.
            ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
            try {
                outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.i("ERROR", "Unable to write file contents.");
            }
            // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
            // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
            // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                        intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i("ERROR", "Failed to launch file chooser.");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
        // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
        // failures.
        // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Also Implements `ConnectionCallbacksand` and
`OnConnectionFailedListener` Listeners.

Comment: Where will you get the driveId here? I have almost similar code but driveId is always null for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: try `result.getDriveContents().getDriveId() ` for getting `driveId`.

Comment: when you  upload a file or folder it returns a drive id .using that id only we will get that associate file or folder @creepy_driver

Comment: @AsifPatel Thanks a lot  for your solution.And how can i download a image or can i show this image to user.I am saving this image in appfolder.